# ReactJs state not update after change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a drop down for select user location, it works but there is an issue, you can see demo **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/n9y0umgq/1/)**.

As you can see there is a pre-selected fields right? This comes from the database, this means that a user selected it before, now click on submit, and check console.

It looks like you got right value, but now if you change province then city and then district and click on submit again the district value is wrong, it still has the initial value + the new value.

How can I solve this?

What I tried so far is to make a tricky refresh for district state like this:

```
getDistrict = (e, data) => {
    this.setState({
        districtValue: null // here I make it null
    }, () => {
        this.setState({
            districtValue: data.value // after call back fill it again
        })
    });
    console.log(data.value) // but already return previous one + new one
}
```

Comment: Why down vote?!

Comment: Just do `getDistrict = (e, data) => {
        this.setState({
            districtValue: data.value
        });
    }`

Comment: @AjayDabas Oh come on, If it work I never made a `callback` and do a tricky way to refresh state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see changes :
commented with // this line

```
const {
  Dropdown
} = semanticUIReact


class App extends React.Component {

  state = { 
              DistrictData: null,
            ProvinceData: null,
            CityData: null,
            provinceValue: null,
            cityValue: null,
            districtValue: null
  }

componentDidMount() {
    const Data = {
    ProvinceData: [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Istanbul"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Ankara"
    }
                  ],
    CityData: [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Istanbul",
      "pid" : "1"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Ankara",
      "pid" : "2"
    }
              ],
    DistrictData: [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "sisli",
        "cid" : "1"
      }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "istiklal",
        "cid" : "1"
      }, {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "taksim",
        "cid" : "1"
      },{
        "id": "4",
        "name": "mahmut pasa",
        "cid" : "2"
      },{
        "id": "5",
        "name": "edirine",
        "cid" : "1"
      },{
        "id": "6",
        "name": "soltan ahmat",
        "cid" : "1"
      },{
        "id": "7",
        "name": "galata",
        "cid" : "1"
      },{
        "id": "8",
        "name": "kizilay",
        "cid" : "2"
      }

    ]};
            this.setState({
            DistrictData: Data.DistrictData,
            ProvinceData: Data.ProvinceData,
            CityData: Data.CityData,
            provinceValue: "1",
            cityValue: "1",
            districtValue: ["5"]
        })
}


    getProvince = (e, {value}) => {
        this.setState({
            provinceValue: value,
            districtValue: [] // this line
        });

    };

    getCity = (e, {value}) => {
        this.setState({
            cityValue: value,
            districtValue: [] // this line
        });
    };

    getDistrict = (e, data) => {
        this.setState({
            districtValue: [] // this line
        }, () => {
            this.setState({
                districtValue: data.value
            }, console.log(data.value))
        });

    }

    check = (e) => {
        console.log(this.state.provinceValue)
        console.log(this.state.cityValue)
        console.log(this.state.districtValue)
    }

render() {
        const ProvinceOptions = this.state.ProvinceData && this.state.ProvinceData.map((v, index) => ({
            key: index,
            text: v.name,
            value: v.id,
        }));
        const CityOptions = this.state.CityData && this.state.CityData.filter(x => x.pid === this.state.provinceValue).map((v,i)  =>{
            return {
                key: i,
                value : v.id,
                text: v.name
            }
        });
        const DistrictOptions = this.state.DistrictData && this.state.DistrictData.filter(x => x.cid === this.state.cityValue).map((v,i)  =>{
            return {
                key: i,
                value : v.id,
                text: v.name
            }
        });

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Province</label>
      <Dropdown
        search selection
        options={ProvinceOptions}
        onChange={this.getProvince}
        value={this.state.provinceValue}
        />
      <label>City</label>
      <Dropdown
        search selection
        options={CityOptions}
        onChange={this.getCity}
        value={this.state.cityValue}
        />
      <label>District</label>
      <Dropdown
        selection multiple search
        options={DistrictOptions}
        onChange={this.getDistrict}
        value={this.state.districtValue}
        />
        <button onClick={this.check}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: `getDistrict` can be changed back with-out the "tricky" refresh - like the other `onChange` handlers. Please add to your answer what's the important change in your code. I also played a bit with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/bhq87x4y/5/) but you've answered faster.